# logstash read csv attachment from imap

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, imap, logstash-configuration

So I try to understand how IMAP input plugins works. My use case is read .csv attachment from email. I didnt find any documentation about how to do this.
I need configuration example of IMAP input plugin since the official didn't give it clear enough for me.
Is logstash able to parse csv attachment while reading email using IMAP?

I saw [IMAP official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-imap.html#plugins-inputs-imap-strip_attachments) mentioned `save_attachments` and `strip_attachments` but it doesn't tell me clearly what it does

My usecase:
read email attachment which is .csv format and ingest it to elasticsearch.

questions:

1. Can logstash parse csv and ingest it to elasticsearch using IMAP plugin? or this IMAP plugin only read email and unable to parse the inside of its attachment?
2. How do we do the configuration since the official documentation don't make it clear enough for me